# Caliper Integration with local ethereum network giving json path error

Tags: go-ethereum, hyperledger, benchmark, hyperledger-fabric

I am using hyperledger-caliper for the benchmarking of my private ethereum network. I followed their official source for the setting it up and get into work with ethereum. But I'm getting error shown here:

> Error: You must provide the json interface of the contract when instantiating a contract object.

Here is the networkconfig.json file

```
    {
    "caliper": {
        "blockchain": "ethereum",
        "command" : {}
    },
    "ethereum": {
        "url": "ws://localhost:7545",
        "contractDeployerAddress": "0x5B14D7452573edB2ABe4941286618Fc09F1Ae085",
        "contractDeployerAddressPassword": "a0969bdb33adfb905d0d94cf4d6b1f63ebee447a17b80972f16e178bd0b219df",
        "fromAddress": "0x5B14D7452573edB2ABe4941286618Fc09F1Ae085",
        "fromAddressPassword": "a0969bdb33adfb905d0d94cf4d6b1f63ebee447a17b80972f16e178bd0b219df",
        "transactionConfirmationBlocks": 2,
        "contracts": {
            "simple": {
                "path": "/home/madddii/Documents/caliper-benchmarks/src/ethereum/simple/simple.json",
                "estimateGas": true,
                "gas": {
                    "query": 100000,
                    "transfer": 70000
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The command which I am using for running it up is:

```
caliper launch manager --caliper-workspace . --caliper-networkconfig ./networks/ethereum/1node-clique/networkconfig.json --caliper-benchconfig benchmarks/scenario/simple/config.yaml --caliper-flow-only-test --caliper-fabric-gateway-enabled -v
```

Can you please help me out in figuring the solution of this problem.

Comment: I was wondering how to test Ethereum with Caliper. Can you provide a detailed tutorial

Comment: you can reach out to me at hali.bese18seecs@gmail.com or 
https://www.linkedin.com/in/hammadali018/

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue in caliper 0.4.2, it seems that documentation is not updated accordingly.
I dig a bit into the code and found that an invalid reference is used.
To resolve your issue just add ABI and deployed ADDRESS of the contract to the network configuration file.

```
{
    "caliper": {
        "blockchain": "ethereum",
        "command" : {}
    },
    "ethereum": {
        "url": "ws://localhost:7545",
        "contractDeployerAddress": "0x5B14D7452573edB2ABe4941286618Fc09F1Ae085",
        "contractDeployerAddressPassword": "a0969bdb33adfb905d0d94cf4d6b1f63ebee447a17b...",
        "fromAddress": "0x5B14D7452573edB2ABe4941286618Fc09F1Ae085",
        "fromAddressPassword": "a0969bdb33adfb905d0d94cf4d6b1f63ebee447a17b...",
        "transactionConfirmationBlocks": 2,
        "contracts": {
            "simple": {
                "path": "/home/madddii/Documents/caliper-benchmarks/src/ethereum/simple/simple.json",
                "estimateGas": true,
                "gas": {
                    "query": 100000,
                    "transfer": 70000
                },
                "abi": [{ < here comes your abi > }],
                "address": "< here comes your contract address with 0x>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps, it worked for me.